# Why does `gem update rake` ask me about an executable conflict?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I ran gem update and got this message:

```
rake's executable "rake" conflicts with /Users/jonytucci/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

I am still pretty new to all this and am unsure of what this means or what to do. Can someone please enlighten me on what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to [a long-standing bug in RubyGems](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5060). It's not specific to rbenv. It happens when you install a new version of a gem that comes with Ruby and has an executable in Ruby's bin directory. rake and rdoc are two such gems.

In most situations you can safely answer yes and let RubyGems overwrite the old version of the executable.